# Yii Default Scope with 2 possible Conditions based on if statement

Tags: yii

I'm kinda new with MVC and Yii, and I'm trying to have 2 roles for users. I use User and Rights modules. Students can view, edit, create records but only own records (where userId is their Id) and tutors should be able to view only the records assigned to them in another column tutorId for each record.

I am trying to use defaultScope but it ignores the if statement and goes directly to the first condition always.

This is my code:

```
public function defaultScope()
{         
    if($userId=Yii::app()->user->id){
        return array(
            'condition'=>'userid='.Yii::app()->user->id, //Scope is limited to logged in user only            
        );     
    } else {
        echo "You have Read Only Access";
        return array(
            'condition'=>'tutorid='.Yii::app()->user->id, //Scope is limited to tutor Id for each record           
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `defaultScope` is evil. Use scopes.

Comment: condition `$userId=Yii::app()->user->id` always returns true. use `if(Yii::app()->user->id)` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
public function defaultScope()
{         
    if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('tutor') == false)
    {
        return array(
            'condition'=>'userid='.Yii::app()->user->id, //Scope is limited to logged in user only            
        );     
    } else {
        echo "You have Read Only Access";
        return array(
            'condition'=>'tutorid='.Yii::app()->user->id, //Scope is limited to tutor Id for each record           
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man! now I can finally sleep. So little help for Yii v1 out there.